# Math Jax isn't working as it used to

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

In the last days, I always needed to refresh the page after I clicked on something like 1 new answer, or this post was edited, else mathjax didn't render the $\LaTeX$ code. About 2 weeks ago, when I started using SE it always rendered without loading the page again.

I use Google Chrome and I have windows 8, in the comments one mentioned the same problems on vista with firefox.

Here is an image of the error
[image: the real error]

[image: another one]

Comment: I have not noticed anything like this. Perhaps it is a browser issue. If you haven't recently, try restarting your browser and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I have noticed this as well, when I'm already in a question and either an existing post is edited or another answer is posted. The old behaviour was that on clicking to see the edit/new post, the Mathjax wasn't formatted properly. Now it isn't formatted at all. I'm running Firefox 18.0.2 on Vista. I think I assumed it to be a browser problem.

Comment: I use Chrome on Windows 8, the old behaviour was that it wasn't formatted properly as Peter mentioned, the math code and the text overlayed

Comment: I get the same problem with Chrome on my Mac (sorry, not sure of the operating system name).

Comment: My experience too. The content fetched when I click `N new answers` somehow escapes client-side scripts, and not only MathJax.  Chrome 25/Win7.

Comment: Hm. I definitely saw this behavior in recent days, but can't reproduce it today. Anyone have a recent screenshot, or precise steps to reproduce the bug?

Comment: @5pm, see my "answer" for a screen shot.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on the *question list* page; is this limited to answers / edits on the *individual question*'s page?

Comment: yeah the effect is limited to an individual question page

Comment: I have a confirmed repro on the individual question page; looking

Comment: @MarcGravell maybe if you mean this, that happens sometimes to me

Comment: There are two different issues here: (1) the screenshot of Dominic Michaelis shows that happens when a formula fits only partially into whatever number of characters is used for "question summary". Naturally, a cut-off formula cannot be rendered by MathJax. (2) The screenshot by Peter Phipps shows that an answer fetched by the page via "1 new answer" escapes MathJaX processing altogether (this may be browser-dependent).

Comment: @5pm i have the same problem as peter i will upload a second screenshot, the first one is the old problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue of posts loaded via the real-time notifications (edits, new answers, etc) now been rectified and will go out in the next deploy.

I have not yet looked at the issue relating to truncated descriptions (that image wasn't there at the time).

Comment: Does "this" refer specifically to the "new answer" bug? One of two screenshots in the OP shows non-rendered partial formulas in question summary, which are cut off because they did not fit into the allotment of characters for the summary. This looks like a different issue.

Comment: @5pm noted and clarified

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but a reply to 5pm's request for a screenshot.

The precise steps involved me opening a new question, waiting for an answer to appear, and clicking on the "A new answer is available, click to load" button.

It's not the best example I suppose but the Mathjax is clearly unformatted.
[image: unformated mathjax]

The question was [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320379/how-to-find-all-the-ideals-of-a-given-norm).

Comment: i got something like that too, but i can't upload it

Comment: @DominicMichaelis, if you edit your question you can click the Image icon above the edit box, and upload the image from your pc or wherever.

Comment: I did but it doesn't load is png not supported ?

Comment: I'm sure png is supported, though I saved mine as a jpeg from MS Paint.

Comment: Ok right now it did work, but i am waiting for a better example

Comment: @DominicMichaelis that (it not accepting your image) was a separate issue - now fixed